# date -d: what are the accepted strings?

Tags: date

I am using the "date" command to perform some simple date arithmetic. The "-d" option lets me do this, but the man pages are very unclear on what is valid data. What are all the accepted options, and how do I figure that out?

I can use this command to determine the date 5 minutes ago: date -d "5-minutes-ago" +%H:%M

This command also works: date -d "-5 minutes" +%H:%M

I stumbled upon these options by accident/frustration. I don't see a "minutes-ago" or a "-X minutes" option listed in the documentation.

I would use Perl to do the arithmetic, but unfortunately I cannot install any additional Perl packages.

Comment: If you have `gawk`, it will do date arithmetic.

Comment: You can do date aritmatic in bash/sh by keeping the dates in UNIX timestamps, just until you need to represent them to a user. Then the date command can convert the timestamp into a string (see example below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few relative date strings.  `minutes ago` works (vs. `minutes-ago` with the dash).

There are quite a few examples on the coreutils `date` info pages:

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

A tricky one is the UNIX timestamp format (this is useful if you are managing a textfile database -- you want to keep your date/time data as UNIX timestamps so you can perform interger math on them)

```
$ date +%s
1299273353
$ date -d @1299273353
Fri Mar  4 15:15:53 CST 2011
```

The at-sign tells the date command that the number is a UNIX timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install additional packages to handle date math in Perl; just use [time()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html) to get an epoch offset, and [localtime()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) to convert it to a useful date data structure.